# How to use CultureInfo with Utf8Parser?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to parse float value both coma-as-decimal-point and dot-as-decimal-point. I write my custom System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter.

naive realization:

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
{
    CultureInfo englishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
                
    if (decimal.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Float, englishCulture, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    CultureInfo russianCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
    if (decimal.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Float, russianCulture, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

zero-alocation memory realization

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = reader.HasValueSequence 
                                    ? reader.ValueSequence.ToArray() 
                                    : reader.ValueSpan;

    if (Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out result, out int bytesConsumed) 
                        && span.Length == bytesConsumed)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

how should i pass CultureInfo to Utf8Parser?

Comment: You are really asking about Encoding.  Encoding is used to save memory by mapping 16 bit characters into 8 bits.  So in general all Encoding methods are the same for 0x00 to 0x7F.  Then for 0x80 to 0xFF different 16 bit characters are mapped into 8 bits characters.  UTF8 ignores encoding and treats the characters as 8 bits.  So a nothing need to be done to pass Culture to UTF8.   When you parse you need to use the hex value to locate characters instead of the actual characters.  For example with French Fonts the characters 0x97 may be different from the Russia 0x97 character.

Comment: The json format has no culture. [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: Alex you're right but parsing have.

Comment: Utf8Parser parses Number tokens by itself and returns them as ready-made numbers. He doesn't need culture for that. | I see you parse the JsonTokenType.String tokens as numbers. This has nothing to do with Utf8Parser, because it has already finished its work at this stage: it returned string values to you.

Comment: Numbers in json are presented without quotes: `"price": 5.5`. Utf8Parser will deal with them by itself. You seem to be parsing numbers enclosed in quotation marks: `"price": "5.5"`. IMHO, it is necessary to figure out where such values in JSON came from. Why numbers are represented as strings. Ask this question to the person who supplies you with such JSON.

Comment: Alexander you're right json format is invalid. But the question of dealing with Utf8Parser is imho very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck. Utf8Parser hard-codes the decimal period, so no cake for you.

See for yourself in the reference source code. The source file in question is *Utf8Parser.Number.cs*, the relevant code is inside the *TryParseNumber* method:

```
int numDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;
if (c == Utf8Constants.Period)
{
    //
    // Parse the digits after the decimal point.
    //


    srcIndex++;
    int startIndexDigitsAfterDecimal = srcIndex;

    ...
```

([link to dotnet/runtime github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3c21cc5a0a486d08b5a7a4fdc2e1c2f9b02dbc9f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Text/Utf8Parser/Utf8Parser.Number.cs#L127-L135))

Note how a byte `c` from the UTF-8 text is compared against `Utf8Constants.Period`. :-(((

---

As with regard to the comments underneath the question:

- Whether a text representation of a floating point number uses a decimal period or a decimal comma has nothing to do with text encodings whatsoever. As the question correctly points out, decimal period vs. comma is a Culture/Locale thing. (Considerations as to why a floating point number is being presented as a string but not as a number in the asker's Json data notwithstanding...)
- How would it be possible to map 16-bit characters (2^16 unique characters) to just 8-bit characters? That's simply not possible, unless 2^16-256 of the 16-bit characters are discarded. Also, what has been said about UTF-8 in the comments is just plain wrong. UTF-8 is not an 8-bit encoding. Not every character representable in UTF-8 is just 8 bits. UTF-8 is a variable-width character encoding. The number of bytes (more specific: octets) used by characters in UTF-8 range from 1...4 octets. (The "8" in UTF-8 refers to the bit width of the code unit, here the octet. Similarily, the "16" UTF-16 refers to the code unit being 16 bits wide, with characters in UTF-16 being made of 1...2 16-bit words.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Than please suggest how can i convert ReadOnlySpan<byte> to ReadOnlySpan<char> and is it sutable/acceptable?

PS to use with f.e. TryParse(ReadOnlySpan<Char>, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Decimal)